# Migrate from Sony Ericsson W810i to Galaxy

Tags: data-transfer, contacts, sms

I just bought my new Galaxy S. My old mobile phone is Sony Ericsson W810i. I wonder if I can do something in order to migrate my SMS and contacts. For example I was thinking the following:

Connect w810 with my computer, copy the folders from memory stick and phone memory and paste them into Galaxy. Is this feasible?

Edit: Just noticed that I havent accepted an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1. The base way is to sync your contacts to your Gmail account from your Sony Ericsson W810i if that is possible. Then sync that account to your Galaxy and your contacts will be copied OTA easily.

Method 2. Sync all your contacts from your Sony Ericsson to Outlook. Then export those contacts from outlook to a CSV file. Once you have your contacts in CSV file you can import that CSV file to your Gmail account and then sync that Gmail account to your Galaxy S 2 and you are DONE.

Comment: Hi,I already have my contacts in vcf. Can I make the same process? What about sms? My phone exploerer would work for me?

Comment: here ia a hint *.vcf file can be opened in Windows Contacts Application and the exported as *.csv file (thats for windows) and vcf file can bee opened in MacOS Address Book Application..Bothe of those appliation are included in Vista and Mac OS respectively...

Comment: SMS can be backed up using BackUpRoot or Titanium BackUp applications from the market :) and can be restored as well..Good Luck

Comment: We have some progresss. I managed to back the up to xml and downlodedsms back up and restore. But when I load them it gets a null exception. Any ideas?

Comment: vcf can also be imported into Google Contacts, which syncs seamlessly with Android.

Answer (score 2):

Sync contacts to your Gmail should be your best choice, it is very easy and does not cost you money. If you have not done that, you will need some third-party program to transfer your contacts to Galaxy.

Comment: Hi Jesson, thanks for the answer. I have done it that way, just forgot to mark the above answe as accepted :)

Comment: It does not matter. Glad I can help you.